# Dipolar field in terms of demag. tensor

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, differential-geometry

Assuming a potential as
$$\Phi=\frac{1}{4\pi}\oint_S \frac{\vec M(\vec r')\cdot\hat n}{|\vec r - \vec r'|}da' \tag{1}\label{1}$$

where the integral can be written as

$$\int_V \nabla' \left(\frac{\vec M(\vec r')}{|\vec r - \vec r'|}dV'\right).$$

Then, if $M$ is constant

$$\Phi = \left(\frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{V} \frac{(\vec r - \vec r')}{|\vec r - \vec r'|^3}dV'\right) M$$

And the dipolar field can be taken as the gradient of that potential. Then

$$H_{d}=\sum_{i} \left[\frac{-1}{4\pi}\frac{\partial}{\partial_{i}n_{i}}\int_{V} \frac{(\vec r - \vec r')}{|\vec r - \vec r'|^3}dV'\right]$$
where $n_i$ is the scalar factor.

My question is where does this factor came from and why.

Comment: Please use mathjax and not images pasted in, I have added the 1st equation, you should do the rest. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/

Comment: I think in eqs. (4) and (5)  instead of $\partial x_i$ you meant to write $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$

Answer (score 1):

The divergence theorem takes you from equation 1 to equation 2.
The scale factor comes from the definition of the gradient in a specific coordinate system, so that $\hat e$ will be a unit vector.